# how to restrict website access to a couple of web pages and ip address only, using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using following

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/temp_page.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/thanks.php$

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^90\.333\.222\.111
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1

RewriteRule $ /temp_page.php [R=302,L]
```

can allow myself (ip) to view all pages, and other get to view only temp_page and thanks.php. I've images and css files linked on temp_page and thanks.php but they dont work, how do I modify RewriteCond so that it allows /js/*.*, /css/*.*, and /images/*.* as well??

please let me know if need more info.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
```

should work.